# Error "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I am working on sender and receiver in `windows application` using socket/tcplistener.

I am getting this error

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
>   is normally permitted

Error is coming in catch block of `StartReciever` method

Below is my code.

```
// On button click
private void btnLoadFile_SendFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

       StartReciever();
       SendData(tcpIpAddress, port, filename);
      }


  private void StartReciever()
        {
            util.LoadSettings();

            string tcpIpAddress = util.svrSettings["IpAddress"];
            string port = util.svrSettings["Port"];
            string outDir = util.svrSettings["isOutput"];

            new Thread(
        () =>
        {
            if (!File.Exists(util.settingFile))
                Logger("Please setup the services first.");
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(tcpIpAddress);
                    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, Convert.ToInt32(port));

                    tcpListener.Start();

                    Logger("\nWaiting for a client to connect...");

                    //blocks until a client connects
                    Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

                    Logger("\nClient connected");

                    //Read data sent from client
                    NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                    int bytesReceived, totalReceived = 0;

                    string fileName = "testing.txt";

                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[10000];
                    do
                    {
                        bytesReceived = networkStream.Read
                            (receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length);
                        totalReceived += bytesReceived;
                        Logger("Progress of bytes recieved: " + totalReceived.ToString());
                        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                        {
                            using (File.Create(fileName)) { };
                        }

                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append))
                        {
                            stream.Write(receivedData, 0, bytesReceived);
                        }

                    }
                    while (bytesReceived != 0);
                    Logger("Total bytes read: " + totalReceived.ToString());

                    socketForClient.Close();
                    Logger("Client disconnected...");

                    tcpListener.Stop();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Error : "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"     
                    Logger("There is some error: " + ex.Message); 
                }
            }
        }).Start();
        }



 private static void SendData(string tcpIpAddress, string port, string filename)
        {
            new Thread(
      () =>
      {
          TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(tcpIpAddress, Convert.ToInt32(port));
          //const int bufsize = 8192;
          const int bufsize = 10000;
          var buffer = new byte[bufsize];
          NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

          using (var readFile = File.OpenRead(filename))
          {
              int actuallyRead;
              while ((actuallyRead = readFile.Read(buffer, 0, bufsize)) > 0)
              {
                  networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, actuallyRead);
              }
          }
      }).Start();
        }
```

Comment: Please note that error occurs when I click on button 2nd time. 1st click doesn't throw any error

Comment: You are initializing the listener every time the button is clicked, therefore the second attempt is throwing this exception. You should initialize and start the listener only once.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the receiver started by the first button click is still running, so when you try to set up a second `TcpListener` on the same address and port, you get the exception.

You should add some code that prevent you from creating two identical listeners in parallel.

Comment: any idea how to do the same that you suggested because I was looking for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You call `StartReceiver` method right in your Click event handler, that's why it tries to open the same port the second time. It only needs to be called once, move it elsewhere, say in your program initialization code.